# ! Missing delimiter (. inserted). <to be read again>

Tags: math-mode

I can't figure out why my code won't work. I need an answer as soon as possible.

```
\[
\begin{split}
\therefore \delta F \left(E_{x} \right )&=\int \left [ \frac{\partial F}{\partial E }\delta E+\frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{E}}\delta \dot{E}\right ]dx=0\\
&=\int\left {\left[\frac{\partial H_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial H_{y}}{\partial x}-2i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon \\E_{x} \right ]\delta E_{x}-\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left ( \frac{\partial F}{\partial E/\partial x}\right )+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left ( \frac{\partial F}{\partial E/\partial y}\right )+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left ( \frac{\partial F}{\partial E/\partial z}\right )\right ]\delta E_{x}\right } \ dx\\
&=\int\left[\left(\frac{\partial H_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial H_{y}}{\partial x}-2i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon \\E_{x} \right ) - \left(-\frac{\partial H_{z}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial H_{y}}{\partial x} \right )\right ]\delta E_{x} \ dx\\
&=\int 2 \(\frac{\partial H_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial H_{y}}{\partial x}-i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon \\E_{x}\)\delta E_{x} \ dx &=0.
\end{split}
\]
```

The error I get is:

! Missing delimiter (. inserted).

{
l.50     \end{split}

Please help!

Comment: cells such as `\\E_{x} \right ]`  have a `\right` with no matching `\left`

Comment: To elaborate, between `\left` and `\right`, you can't have `&` nor `\\ `.  Also, `\left{` won't work.  If you want a literal `{`, you need to type `\{`, so that you'd have `\left\{`.

Comment: To be expand on David's comment, you need to match your `\left` and `\right` commands. Note that most of the time you don't need to use these unless you have an inner content that will require larger than usual delimiters. If for some reason you need unbalanced delimiters, you can use `\left.` or `\right.` to create an invisible left or right delimiter.

Comment: i also see a `\(` on the last light which I imagine was meant to be `\left(`

Answer (score 3):

You have some misplaced `\\` before `E_x`

I'd avoid `\left` and `\right` for this display, preferring `\bigg` size. In any case, `\left` and `\right` cannot straddle different parts of the alignment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\therefore \delta F(E_{x})
  &=\int \biggl[ \pder{F}{E}\delta E+\pder{F}{\dot{E}}\delta \dot{E} \biggr]\,dx=0 \\[2ex]
  &=\int
    \biggl\{
      \biggl[
        \pder{H_{z}}{y}-\pder{H_{y}}{x}-2i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon E_{x}
      \biggr]\delta E_{x} \\
  &\qquad\quad
      -\biggl[
        \pder{}{x}
        \biggl( \pder{F}{E/\partial x} \biggr)+\pder{}{y} \biggl( \pder{F}{E/\partial y} \biggr)
        +\pder{}{z} \biggl( \pder{F}{E/\partial z} \biggr)
      \biggr]\delta E_{x}
    \biggr\}\,dx \\[2ex]
  &=\int
    \biggl[
      \biggl(\pder{H_{z}}{y}-\pder{H_{y}}{x}-2i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon E_{x} \biggr)
      -
      \biggl(-\pder{H_{z}}{y}+\pder{H_{y}}{x} \biggr)
    \biggr]\delta E_{x} \, dx\\[2ex]
&=\int 2
  \biggl(
    \pder{H_{z}}{y}-\pder{H_{y}}{x}-i\omega\varepsilon_{0}\varepsilon E_{x}
  \biggr)\delta E_{x} \, dx\\[2ex]
& =0.
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

The second integral needs to be split across lines, I added some spacing to make clear that the third line is a continuation of the second one and also added vertical spaces between main lines.

An abbreviation for partial derivatives has been defined, to ease input.

[image]

I'd also omit the `\therefore` symbol: just spell out “therefore” before the display.